# pytorch-lightning train_dataloader object taking forever to loop through the data

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

I have an LSTM model which I want to use for time forecasting. I have a class that extends `pl.LightningDataModule` and in this class I am trying to create data loaders to train my model.

## Class BTCPriceDataModule

```
class BTCPriceDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):

    def __init__(self, train_sequences, test_sequences, batch_size = 8):
        super().__init__()
        self.train_sequence = train_sequences
        self.test_sequences = test_sequences
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def setup(self, stage=None):
        self.train_dataset = BTCDataset(self.train_sequence)
        self.test_dataset = BTCDataset(self.test_sequences)

    def train_dataloader(self):
        print("coming here")
        return DataLoader(
            self.train_dataset,
            batch_size = self.batch_size,
            shuffle = False,
            num_workers=2
        )
    
    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
            self.test_dataset,
            batch_size=1,
            shuffle=False,
            num_workers=1
        )

    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
            self.test_dataset,
            batch_size=1,
            shuffle=False,
            num_workers=1
        )
```

## Class BTCDataset

```
class BTCDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,sequences):
        self.sequences = sequences
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.sequences)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sequence, label = self.sequences[idx]

        return dict(
            sequence=torch.Tensor(sequence.to_numpy()),
            label = torch.tensor(label).float()
        )
```

When I run `trainer.fit()` my sanity check takes forever to complete so I started to debug my code to check if there is any problem while processing the data. When I pass my sequential data through the DataLoader it never is able to even finish one single loop. Example:

```
data_module = BTCPriceDataModule(train_sequences, test_sequences, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
data_module.setup()

for i in data_module.train_dataloader():
    print(i['sequence'].shape)
    print(i['label'].shape)
    break
```

This loop never finishes. I think I gave it enough time and also reduced my dataset size but still it would not compile. `len(data_module.train_dataloader())` is 1921 so I am pretty sure it is not very heavy on my CPU to take more than 5 minutes to compile.
How can I debug this problem? Or is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

changing `num_workers = 0` worked for me.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).